# Build SSH Connection without IP Address

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, ip, dhcp

I have a Ubuntu server in one of our office Local Area Network. I want to connect my server within the LAN via Ubuntu terminal on another PC. I used below command to connect,

```
ssh dush@10.1.4.113
```

But after few days it's IP address was changed because of it's dynamic. Now I couldn't reach the server physically and I know only its username ("dush"), old dynamic IP address ("10.4.1.113") and password.

How can I connect to the server?

Is there a way to connect without current IP address?

Comment: Either you need to know the IP address, or you have to have a DNS server that knows the IP address. If it is a server that needs to be connected to, why does it have a dynamic address and not a static one?

Comment: I not set IP as static, it has default settings. So it change when after reconnect to the network.

Comment: I know you didn't, or you wouldn't be having this problem.

Comment: So, is there a way to solve that?

Comment: Yes. Assign the server a static IP address.